# Dashboard customization in Kibana 4.0

Tags: dashboard, kibana

> I am trying to customize my Kibana dashboard v 4.0, can anyone suggest a way out?

Comment: depends what you mean by customise - are you just looking to change the colour scheme, or add different visualisations?

Comment: Please be more elaborate about your Problem and mention what you have tried and when their results were, if you have some code you can show please do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can customize and as well as you can create custom dashboards. Depending on your saved search you can customize your dashboard with different visualizations.